# JavaScript Set Parent Value from Child Class

Tags: javascript

I am in JavaScript.

Below I have a **Main** object that instantiates the **Handle** class within it. I prefer **composition** over inheritance which is why I've *avoided prototyping* -- unless there is a way around it..

```
function Main() {

  this.changeMe = 1;

  this.init = function() {
    handle = new Handle();
    handle.setMe();

  }
};

function Handle() {
  this.setMe = function() {
     // parent::changeMe = 2; <-- How would I change the parent value?    
  }
};

var app = new Main();
main.init();
console.log(main.changeMe); <-- How do I get that to 2?
```

I am trying to figure out how I change the parent value. Do you know how?

Comment: `Handle` isn't inheriting from `Main`, so technically `Main` isn't its parent... You could circularly pass `this` (the instance of `Main`) into the `Handle()` initializer to give a recursive parent/child accessor but that kind of defeats the point

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4ag6v/1/

Answer (score 0):

The init code is wrong here, syntax error..
You are creating new object of Main() in app variable yet trying to access it from 'main' variable which is not initialized.

try

```
var app = new Main();
app.init();
console.log(app.changeMe);
```